# Movie clips capture from camcorders over firewire in Debian testing/unstable

Tags: linux, debian, camera, firewire

What is the best way to capture clips from camcorders over firewire?
When I did it last time 1+ year ago I used Kino and the raw1394 kernel
driver. When I tried to do it this week with the latest kernel in
testing (2.6.32 I believe), I noticed that the raw1394 module is not
provided with the stock kernel any more.

Could someone suggest a way to capture clips without this driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [dvgrab](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dvgrab).  Example:

```
dvgrab foo-
```

Captures video data from the default IEEE1394 source and stores it to files foo-001.avi, foo-002.avi, etc. To create a single mpeg file, you can pipe dvgrab to [ffmpeg](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg):

```
dvgrab -format dv1 - | ffmpeg -f dv -i - -target ntsc-vcd foo.mpg
```

See [this post](http://regx.dgswa.com/html/?q=node/65) for some more examples